# Always making a new DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I followed a tutorial but I didn't like the result, so I am trying to optimise it but I can't seem to find a way around always making a new dataframe. And I know it is a result from the while loop.
So what i want is the price to append to the dataframe i made.
**Thanks in advance!**

```
import pandas as pd
import bs4
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime

#getting actual price
def Real_time_Price(stock):
    url = ('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+stock+'?p='+stock)
    r=requests.get(url)
    web_content=BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    web_content = web_content.find('div',{'class':"My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)"})
    web_content = web_content.find('span').text
    
    return web_content
```

and here is where my problem starts

```
while True:    
    price = []
    col = []
    time_stamp = datetime.datetime.now()
    #de milli seconden wegknallen.
    time_stamp = time_stamp.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    #welke stocks wilje checken
    ticker_symbols = ['TSLA','AAPL','MSFT']

    for stock in ticker_symbols:
        price.append(Real_time_Price(stock))


    #getting it into a pandas dataframe
    #You want [data] for pandas to understand they're rows.
    df=pd.DataFrame(data=[price], index=[time_stamp], columns=ticker_symbols)
    print(df)
```

Comment: Perhaps you should change the last line where you construct the dataframe so it uses pd.concat() to add the new information to the old.

Comment: If I want to use concat i need 2 DataFrames but i only have one. It just prints it out again and again. What I'am actually looking for is how to get the new data from the loop in the existing dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create dataframe once and use DataFrame.loc([]) to append

```py
df=pd.DataFrame(index=[time_stamp], columns=ticker_symbols)
while True:
    price = []
    col = []
    time_stamp = datetime.datetime.now()
    #de milli seconden wegknallen.
    time_stamp = time_stamp.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    #welke stocks wilje checken
    ticker_symbols = ['TSLA','AAPL','MSFT']

    for stock in ticker_symbols:
        price.append(Real_time_Price(stock))
    df.loc[time_stamp]=price
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I can't like it yet tho.
This really works thank you, but maybe another little question. Now it still prints all the new dataframes, but with the new info added, isnt there an option to just get the latest  dataframe?

Comment: Get the latest data frame? Please explain.

Comment: So, it prints every new dataframe (new because of the new info that is added every 2 seconds) each time the latest stock info is added. Is there any way i can just print the latest dataframe printed. So it should make a new dataframe with the new stock info every 2 seconds.